# C++ Linking error using libraries libsumo, libtraci, undefined reference to libtraci::Simulation::init()

Tags: c++, eclipse, linker, mingw, sumo

I have a question regarding correctly linking libraries libsumocpp and libtracicpp in Windows.

I'm trying to connect to a sumo server using libsumo in C++ and have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libsumo/libtraci.h>

using namespace libtraci;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

Simulation::init();
//Simulation::start({"sumo", "-c", "Network_02.sumocfg"});
Simulation::setOrder(2);
//Simulation::init();
//Simulation::setOrder(2);

for (int i=0; i<50; i++)
{
    Simulation::step();
}
Simulation::close();
return 0;
}
```

The code above is based on the following C++ code snippet ([this github post)](https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/issues/8773) which tries to connect to a sumo server:

```
I'm trying to connect to the Sumo simulation from multiple traci clients using libtraci. 
This is how I'm starting the simulation:

sumo --remote-port 4001 --num-clients 2 -c config_file.sumocfg

After starting the simulation I'm trying to connect from two traci client using   the 
   code below:

#include <libsumo/libtraci.h>

using namespace libtraci;
int main () {
Simulation::init(4001,21,"localhost");
Simulation::setOrder(3);
for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
Simulation::step();
}
Simulation::close();
return 0;
}
```

As already mentioned, my code is the one adapted above.
I get the following errors when builiding, compiling and linking as the class "Simulation" functions listed under "libsumo/Simulation.h" seem not to be linked correctly:

```
c:/mingw64/bin/../ld.exe: src\Test.o:C:\Users\Lukas\eclipse-ws\Test\Debug/../src/Test.cpp:28: 
undefined reference to `libtraci::Simulation::init(int, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, _iobuf*)'
c:/mingw64/bin/../bin/ld.exe: src\Test.o: in function `main':
C:\Users\Lukas\eclipse-ws\Test\Debug/../src/Test.cpp:30: undefined reference to `libtraci::Simulation::setOrder(int)'
c:/mingw64/bin/../ld.exe: C:\...\Test.cpp:36: undefined reference to `libtraci::Simulation::step(double)'
c:/mingw64/bin/../ C:.../src/Test.cpp:38: undefined reference to `libtraci::Simulation::close(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I guess it is a linking error. I have provided the path (-L "C:\Users\Lukas\eclipse\SUMO\bin") to the libraries "libsumocpp.lib/dll" and "libtracicpp.lib/dll" (-l sumocpp -ltracicpp) in Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> MinGW C++ Linker.
However, it does not work. Does anyone have a clue what might be wrong in my setup?

Best regards,
Lukas

Comment: I am not familiar with your development environment, but wouldn't `-l sumocpp tracicpp` → `-l sumocpp -l tracicpp` help?

Comment: Here's my link call (which is then followed by the error messages)  Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-LC:\\Users\\Lukas\\eclipse\\SUMO\\bin" -o Test.exe "src\\Test.o" -lsumocpp -ltracicpp

Comment: Can you please share which SUMO version you use and whether you built SUMO and libtraci yourself

Answer (score 0):

gcc/binutils uses extension `.a` (or even `.dll.a` for shared libraries) instead of `.lib` (used by MSVC) as library import files.

So to link you should have `lib<name>.a` (static) or `lib<name>.dll.a` (shared) files in a folder pointed to with `-L` and then use `-l<name>` to link with the library.

gcc (not sure about ld) is smart enough to know the `.dll` itself is a shared library, so you can even specify the the path of a `.dll` file and it will know you want to link against that shared library.

Comment: If the problem was not finding the libraries, the error would be different, so this is unlikely to have anything to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> `undefined reference to libtraci::Simulation::init(int, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<...`

The error suggests that you are compiling your code with `-std=c++11` flag.

But `libtraci` may *not* be built with that flag, and if it's not, then you would get exactly the errors you are getting.

Run `nm -C libtracicpp.lib | grep 'libtraci::Simulation::init'` and see whether anything shows up, and whether the demangled symbol has `::__cxx11::` in it.

If there is no `__cxx11` in the demangled name, you'll need to either rebuild `libtracicpp` with `-std=c++11`, or build your code without that flag (your sample doesn't appear to use any `C++11` features).